# wp7 xamlparseexception initializecomponent

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, xamlparseexception

I have a weird problem. I develop a windows phone 7 app. At first its target windows phone OS version was set to 7.0 (in project properties). Everything worked just fine.

However, after upgrading target OS to version 7.1 I get an exception: XamlParseException "[Line: 0 Position: 0]". An exception occurs in LoginPage.g.i.cs in this method:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public void InitializeComponent() {
        if (_contentLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        _contentLoaded = true;
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/BCMLogic;component/Pages/LoginPage.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));
        this.LayoutRoot = ((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)(this.FindName("LayoutRoot")));
        this.TitlePanel = ((System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel)(this.FindName("TitlePanel")));
        this.image1 = ((System.Windows.Controls.Image)(this.FindName("image1")));
        this.ContentPanel = ((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)(this.FindName("ContentPanel")));
        this.loginBtn = ((System.Windows.Controls.Button)(this.FindName("loginBtn")));
        this.userNameTxt = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)(this.FindName("userNameTxt")));
        this.passTxt = ((System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox)(this.FindName("passTxt")));
        this.clientTxt = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)(this.FindName("clientTxt")));
        this.user = ((System.Windows.Controls.Image)(this.FindName("user")));
        this.passwd = ((System.Windows.Controls.Image)(this.FindName("passwd")));
        this.welcome = ((System.Windows.Controls.Image)(this.FindName("welcome")));
        this.client = ((System.Windows.Controls.Image)(this.FindName("client")));
        this.progressOverlay = ((Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.ProgressOverlay)(this.FindName("progressOverlay")));
    }
}
```

}

Error shows in line: this.LayoutRoot = ((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)(this.FindName("LayoutRoot")));

My main grid in LoginPage.xaml looks like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

 ....

</Grid>
```

Inner exception is null, so I dont get any information there. Is this somehow connected to the fact that referenced by project dlls are not compatibile with the version of OS I upgraded my project to? How do I check this? I spent some time looking through other posts but just couldnt find solution that fitted my problem.

Thanks for help in advance :)